# How to remove all duplicates of ints in an array java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I needed to create a method to remove all occurrences of integers in an array. When the integers are removed, the whole list needs to be shifted down so the empty spaces are filled with the next integers. Currently, this method only removes 1 occurrence of the given integer.

```
public void removeAll(int val) {
    for (int n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {  //goes through each integer
        if (list[n] == val) {  //checks if the value is what the user enters
            for (int j = n; j < list.length - 1; j++) {
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
            }
            list[elements - 1] = 0;  //elements is the amount of elements in the array
            elements--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In its current incarnation, it should remove multiple instances of `val`, if they're not adjacent.  The problem is that when you remove the `n`th value, you're skipping over the `n+1`th value, which has become the `n`th one.  You've also got a problem with the last two (non-brace) lines, which run on every iteration of the loop, instead of just when `val` is found.   Changing `if` to `while`, and moving the `}` down two lines would be a good start, but not a complete solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, you just saved me my computer science grade :)

Comment: I would recommend using the `elements` variable throughout and not `list.length` as the algorithm will break on `val = 0` and list contains a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close:

I would also recommend not using `list.length` but rather `elements` throughout. Otherwise, the algorithm will break when `val = 0` and list contains a `0`.

```
public void removeAll(int val){
    for(int n = 0; n <elements;n++){  // < -- change from list.length to elements
        if(list[n] == val){  
            for (int j = n; j<elements-1;j++){ // < -- change from list.length to elements
                list[j]=list[j+1];
        }
        list[elements-1]=0; 
        elements--;
        n--;  // <-- Add this line to not skip over the 'n + 1'th term
    }
 }
}
```

The problem was that as you were iterating over the collection you were skipping the next term after removal.

For example, say `val = 2` and `list = 1 2 2 3 4 4`:

The algorithm identifies and removes the value:

```
1 2 2 3 4 4
  ^
```

After which your array looks like this and the next position to be checked is `n` which has now been incremented to look at the next item in the collection. It's not hard to see that this would be problematic when items that match the removal criteria are next to each other (adjacent) as in my example.

```
1 2 3 4 4 0
    ^
```

In order to compensate for this event - you need to decrement `n` like so `n--;` when you encounter an item to be removed from the collection. This keeps the `n` looking at the same index in the array until that index is no longer occupied by a to-be-removed item (aka items that match the removal criteria that were adjacent).

**UPDATE**

*What happens if the count of the array is not used as the upper limit throughout and `val = 0` with an array that contains at least one `0`?*

I'll keep with the theme and illustrate the issue with an example.

Let `val = 0` and `list = 1 2 0 3 4 4`. As usual, the algorithm identifies and removes the value.

```
1 2 0 3 4 4
    ^
```

Now the array looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 4 0
    ^
```

However, since the algorithm is still iterating over the collection until index is equal to `list.length` which is still valued at 6 (it's not being decremented like `elements`). The algorithm will eventually end up at the faux item at index 5 of the collection. This is where the trouble begins.

```
1 2 3 4 4 0
          ^
```

The index will never move as there is always going to be another adjacent `0` as we're adding them to the end of the collection to signify unused indexes! Eventually your collection will look like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
          ^
```

In the following iteration - [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) will be thrown by Java as `list[-1] = 0` will occur.

Hope that helps!

Comment: What happens when `val` is zero?

Comment: @DavidWallace: I've added updated my answer and added an example for you. Do you see how not using the relative count of the array will be problematic now?